# error_message: 'the requested product is not yet ready. please provide a webhook or try the request again later',

Tags: reactjs, plaid

I am using https://blog.bitsrc.io/build-a-full-stack-banking-web-app-with-plaid-the-mern-stack-508914ce5694 tutorial to build a bank web app. It is working but when I add another bank account it gives me error in terminal:

> error_code: 'PRODUCT_NOT_READY', error_message: 'the requested product
> is not yet ready. please provide a webhook or try the request again
> later', following error  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'forEach' of null  when I restart the server I can see the new bank
> account and tran#sactions.

Comment: Hi @Ricky. your question needs more code details to people provide a solution to your problem.

Comment: edit your question instead of providing details in comments. add relevant code related to your issue and steps to reproduce there. you can consider including a sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call /transactions/get immediately after Link because Plaid needs a few seconds to initialize transaction data.  That's why you need to wait for a webhook to tell you that transactions are ready.  See [Transactions webhooks](https://plaid.com/docs/transactions/webhooks/) for more info.

As for there uncaught type error, as the other commenters point out, that's not possible to troubleshoot based on the info provided here.